# tls is not working any more in mail configuration

Tags: typo3

i updated a typo3 installation from vs. 8 to 11. In vs 11 the smtp configuration in the install tool is not working anymore:

The following configuration worked until vs. 8:

```
'MAIL' => [
    'transport' => 'smtp',
    'transport_sendmail_command' => '',
    'transport_smtp_encrypt' => 'tls',
    'transport_smtp_password' => 'xyz my password',
    'transport_smtp_server' => 'mymailserver.de:465',
    'transport_smtp_username' => 'user',
],
```

In TYPO3 10 transport_smtp_encrypt changed to bool - a transport_smtp_encrypt = false should activate tls. But this does not work:

```
'MAIL' => [
    'transport' => 'smtp',
    'transport_sendmail_command' => '',
    'transport_smtp_encrypt' => false,
    'transport_smtp_password' => 'xyz my password',
    'transport_smtp_server' => 'mymailserver.de:465',
    'transport_smtp_username' => 'user',
],
```

and this

```
'MAIL' => [
    'transport' => 'smtp',
    'transport_sendmail_command' => '',
    'transport_smtp_encrypt' => false,
    'transport_smtp_password' => 'xyz my password',
    'transport_smtp_server' => 'mymailserver.de:465',
    'transport_smtp_username' => 'user',
],
```

or this

```
'MAIL' => [
    'transport' => 'smtp',
    'transport_sendmail_command' => '',
    'transport_smtp_encrypt' => '',
    'transport_smtp_password' => 'xyz my password',
    'transport_smtp_server' => 'mymailserver.de:465',
    'transport_smtp_username' => 'user',
],
```

do not work either.

I always get the following error:

Could not deliver mail
Please verify $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['MAIL'][*] settings are valid. Error message: Connection could not be established with host "ssl://mymailserver.de:465": stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

Where "SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number" indicates that there is no tls configured. I do need tls, it is the only way the smtp server accepts connections.

Server, port, username and password are correct and identical to the working version in TYPO3 8. Only remaining option is transport_smtp_encrypt but transport_smtp_encrypt is boolean and accepts only true or false or empty.

Any idea whats going on?
Thanks!

Comment: Oehm, you are connecting to port 465, which is normally SMTP over SSL and the error reports problems while connecting "ssl://mymailserver.de:465". Sure, you like to configure TLS instead of SSL?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specified the protocol the server is expecting you can do so with the property "[MAIL][transport_smtp_encrypt]". The error message suggest that your SMTP server expects another TLS version.

First check which protocols your PHP context support by running the following script:

```
<?php
$xportlist = stream_get_transports();
print_r($xportlist);
```

It should output something like this:

```
Array (
[0] => tcp
[1] => udp
[2] => unix
[3] => udg
[4] => ssl
[5] => tls
[6] => tlsv1.0
[7] => tlsv1.1
[8] => tlsv1.2
[9] => tlsv1.3 )
```

Try entering the latest TLS version in that property going down. E.g. tlsv1.3 if that doesn't work tlsv1.2 etc.

Comment: Hello Colin, thanks for your answer! But: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/10.4.x/Important-91070-SMTPTransportOptionTransport_smtp_encryptChangedToBoolean.html - since TYPO3 10 it is not possible anymore to define the protocol with transport_smtp_encrypt. I presume that _is_ the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What protocols does the script output?

You're right it has been removed, I didn't had version 11 at hand to I tried with 12 which should work also. This is the configuration which I can confirm works for port 465:

```
    'MAIL' => [
    'defaultMailFromAddress' => 'yourmail@domain.com',
    'transport' => 'smtp',
    'transport_sendmail_command' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i',
    'transport_smtp_domain' => 'domain.com',
    'transport_smtp_encrypt' => true,
    'transport_smtp_password' => 'password',
    'transport_smtp_server' => 'smtp.hoster.com:465',
    'transport_smtp_username' => 'yourmail@domain.com',
],
```

I think you should try two routes from this:

Make sure you can connect from the server to SMTP via console, you could use mutt for this, which is an email client on the console to connect to IMAP and send mail via SMTP. The setup is usually not that complicated. Just install it on the server and place a .muttrc file in your user folder with the following config:

```
set spoolfile="imaps://user%40domain.de:password@host:993/INBOX"
set smtp_url = "smtp[s]://[user[:pass]@]host[:port]"
```

You should use other SMTP credentials to make sure that the SMTP server isn't outdated and that you have no connection issue.